# Can I make LibreOffice default program for all files

Tags: windows-xp, libreoffice

I have winXP LibreOffice and MS office installed.

How do I make LibreOffice the default opening program for all of its know document types?
I know that I can change one extension at a time. But is there a way to change all of them?

I want LibreOffice to open .doc .xls and ... (I do not know all of them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [here](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=42104):

please try a 'Custom Setup', see
→ Installation of LibreOffice 3.3 on Windows
http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/installation/windows/
especially:
- Dialog Box #6: Choice of Typical or Custom Installation
- Dialog Box #8: Choice for File Type Associations

You may start from 'Add or Remove Programs' > 'LibreOffice...' > 'Modify',
or
(unpacked *.exe file) 'libreoffice33.msi' > right-click 'Install' > 'Modify'.

Comment: Modify did not work, reinstall did. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

'Modify' worked for me. Thanks!

On Windows Vista:

- click START
- Settings
- Control Panel
- Programs
- Programs and Features
- Uninstall a Program
- Select the right program from the list
- click 'change'
- follow instructions.

Comment: Quick update: this worked for me as well on Windows 10.  It's "Apps" now instead of "Programs" but otherwise the steps are the same.

Answer (score 1):

To make office libre the default reader for all your documents:
Right click any document, tap Properties. A box opens that enables you to change the opener to office libre. Do this for a couple documents and OL magically becomes the default opener for all docs of the same type This works for windows 10 at least.

Comment: Do you mean "Do this for a couple documents and OL magically becomes the default opener for all docs."?  The OP probably already knows that.  Or do you mean "Do this for a couple document ***types*** and OL magically becomes the default opener for all doc ***types**.*"?  If so, say so. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: From the question: ''I know that I can change one extension at a time. But is there a way to change all of them?''

Answer (score -2):

For me it worked to just use the "default apps" in windows system settings.

just hit start and type default apps